# Pushing View Controller onto Navigation stack results in SIGABRT

Tags: iphone, mapkit, mkannotationview, sigabrt, accessoryview

Just to preface, I am new to iOS development.  I have looked around for awhile to try and find an answer, whether on here or through Google.

My application loads into a mapview with annotations.  If a user taps on one of the annotations a callout view with an accessory button displays.  The problem I am having is in the method that is called when the accessory button is tapped.  I am wanting to display a detailview for the specific annotation, but when I tap the accessory button the app crashes with SIGABRT.

```
// method that provides the view for when the callout accessory button is tapped
-               (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView 
               annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view 
calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    // grabs the annotation's title from the annotation view
    NSString *viewTitle = view.annotation.title;

    // grabs corresponding POI object for map annotation
    PointOfInterest *object = [[PointOfInterest alloc] init];
    object = [dictionary objectForKey:(NSString *)viewTitle];

    // assigns title and subtitle ivars to variables to be passed into detailviewcontroller init
    NSString *title = object._title;
    NSString *subtitle = object._subtitle;
    UIImage *picture = object._picture;
    NSString *description = object._description;

    // releases POI object after all the information has been taken from it
    [object release];

    // inits detailVC
    DetailVC *detailVC = [[DetailVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailVC" 
                                                    bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    // sets the nsstring ivars in the DVC which correspond to the POI information
    detailVC.thetitleText = title;
    detailVC.thesubtitleText = subtitle;
    detailVC.thepictureImage = picture;
    detailVC.thedescriptionText = description;

    // sets the "back" button on the navigation controller to say "Back to Map"
    UIBarButtonItem *newBackButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back to Map" 
                                                                      style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
                                                                     target:nil 
                                                                     action: nil];
    [[self navigationItem] setBackBarButtonItem: newBackButton];
    [newBackButton release];

    // pushes navcontroller onto the stack and releases the detail viewcontroller
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailVC animated:YES];
    [detailVC release];
}
```

I haven't added the picture and description yet, because I am just trying to get the view to show with the Title and Subtitle.

Here is the DetailViewController class code
**Header:**

```
@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollview;
    IBOutlet UILabel *thetitle;
    NSString *thetitleText;
    IBOutlet UILabel *thesubtitle;
    IBOutlet UIImage *thepicture;
    IBOutlet UITextView *thedescription;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIScrollView *scrollview;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *thetitle;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *thetitleText;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *thesubtitle;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *thepicture;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextView *thedescription;

// method that creates the custom detail view with the corresponding information from
// the point of interest objects
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil title:(NSString*)title subtitle:(NSString *)subtitle picture:(UIImage *)picture description:(NSString *)description;

@end
```

**implementation:**

```
@implementation DetailViewController

@synthesize scrollview, thetitle, thesubtitle, thepicture, thedescription, thetitleText;


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil title:(NSString *)title subtitle:(NSString *)subtitle picture:(UIImage *)picture description:(NSString *)description;
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        NSLog(@"view initialized");
}
return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [scrollview release];
    [thetitle release];
    [thesubtitle release];
    [thepicture release];
    [thedescription release];
    [thetitleText release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"view did load");

    [thetitle setText:self.thetitleText];
    NSLog(@"thetitle text set");


// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
//    [thetitle setText:title];
//    NSLog(@"set title");
//    [thesubtitle setText:subtitle];
//    NSLog(@"set subtitle");
//    thepicture = picture;
//    [thedescription setText:description];
//    NSLog(@"set description");
}
```

Here is the SIGABRT output:

2011-07-12 19:05:06.678 mkeBOAT[1687:ef03] Callout Accessory Tapped

2011-07-12 19:05:06.679 mkeBOAT[1687:ef03] US Bank Tower

2011-07-12 19:05:06.680 mkeBOAT[1687:ef03] (null)

2011-07-12 19:05:06.680 mkeBOAT[1687:ef03] (null), (null)

2011-07-12 19:05:06.680 mkeBOAT[1687:ef03] view initialized

2011-07-12 19:05:06.711 mkeBOAT[1687:ef03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception

'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key description.'

I am don't think the dictionary is working correctly because it is outputting null for the values that should actually have something.

Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: The description of your error seems to imply that either the dictionary isn't seeded with keys, or your object can't handle the key value it's given. Can you check that the POI object can handle what you're giving it?

Comment: did you solve this Bradley ? check out my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you shouldn't do this

```
[detailViewController autorelease];
```

before pushing detailViewController to stack.

you should push it into the navigation stack first then release it since you don't need it anymore and the navigation stack is now the owner of the detailView controller object.

so instead of doing this

```
[detailViewController autorelease];

// this is the line that breaks with SIGABRT
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
```

do this

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
[detailViewController release];
```

More info:

SIGABRT usually happens when there is remaining referencing outlets in your IB but the object in ur controller is not existing anymore.

You should check all your referencing outlets.

Comment: After changing that, still crashing with SIGABRT.

Comment: try checking all your referencing outlets. the is usually the cause of sigbrt

Comment: also try to do this

NSString *viewTitle = view.annotation.title;
NSLog(@"%@", viewTitle);

it might be nil

Comment: It gets past that without issue.  The issue seems to come about when it tries to init the detail view.

Comment: 2011-07-12 18:07:10.954 mkeBOAT[433:ef03] Callout Accessory Tapped
2011-07-12 18:07:10.957 mkeBOAT[433:ef03] US Bank Tower
2011-07-12 18:07:10.957 mkeBOAT[433:ef03] got to init
2011-07-12 18:07:10.957 mkeBOAT[433:ef03] set title
2011-07-12 18:07:10.957 mkeBOAT[433:ef03] set subtitle
2011-07-12 18:07:10.957 mkeBOAT[433:ef03] set description
2011-07-12 18:07:11.682 mkeBOAT[433:ef03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<DetailViewController 0x5a75540> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key description.

Comment: so viewTitle is not nil right? it shows an actual string/message right?

can you show us your code for PointOfInterest class?

Comment: My outlet for what I thought was the imageview was actually set to the view, which is NOT right.  Duh, I feel dumb.  Thanks for the help.  It actually took me just re-writing the view controller for me to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you have your `@property` set to `copy` it should be `retain`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the Class of Files Owner in your XIB is set to DetailViewController.

Comment: Where in the inspector window do I change that?

Comment: Click the identity inspector tab (3rd from the left in Xcode 4) > Custom Class > Class.

Comment: I can change it, but then it just changes back everytime.

Comment: It shouldn't unless you're mistyping the name of the class. Also, try this instead.
[[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController"
                                                                                    bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle];

Answer (score 0):

There is some errors in your implementation :

1) Don't call parent method with fixed value :

self = [super initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];

instead use parameters :

self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];

2) Your thetitle and thesubtitle properties are IBOutlet UILabel but you use copy instead retain, change copy by retain

3) You initialize your UILabel (thetitle and thesubtitle) text in the init method but in this method, the properties are not already defined (thetitle and thesubtitle = nil).

You should instead use NSString properties and set the text of UILabel in the viewDidLoad method with your NSString properties.

And do the same for the UITextField thedescription property.

And don't forget to release all of your properties copied or retained in dealloc and reset your IBOutlet properties in your viewDidUnload method.

For the point 3 :

Add NSString properties to your DetailViewController (and don't forget to synthesize and release it in dealloc) :

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *thetitleText;

next, before pushViewController, add :

detailViewController.thetitleText = title;

and finally in your viewDidLoad method of your DetailViewController, add :

[thetitle setText:self.thetitleText];

And do the same for your other labels.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help!!!  On 3)          - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    [thetitle setText:title];
    NSLog(@"set title");                 says I cannot reference title, how do I pass that parameter in to the viewdidload function?    also how do I goto a new line on a stackoverflow comment without submitting it?

Comment: The `init` method point is a matter of personal preference. I tend to think it breaks encapsulation a bit if another object is telling a `viewController` what xib to use - it implies that another object knows better than the `viewController` itself. Therefore I strip out the `nibName` and `bundle` options and keep them internal.

Comment: You need to have a property for your NSString title that you set before presenting your view controller, i edited my answer to show you how doing that.
Shift + enter to goto a new line but that doesn't add a new line when you submit your comment

Comment: How do I retain the parameters I pass in to the view controller in the view controller?  Should I set the ivars of the DVC in the init method?  If so, what do I do in the viewDidLoad method?

Comment: After changing what you said, it throwing a SIGABRT on main.  
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    // line that causes new SIGABRT
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
    [pool release];
    return retVal;

Answer (score 0):

After restarting and creating a new Detail View Controller, I am pretty sure I had my view linked to the image instead of the actual view.  To compound this, I also believe that my scrollview was really mucking things up.  If anyone would like to see the code that actually works just let me know.  Thank you to all those contributed!!  What a great community SOverflow is!

Answer (score 0):

Read carefully the code...

You **did** initialized `object` using :

`PointOfInterest *object = [[PointOfInterest alloc] init];`.

Why re-assigning `object` like so :

`object = [dictionary objectForKey:viewTitle];` ?

So, no matter in this issue, but here is a leak. Also, I am pretty sure the crash is due to reassigning `object` to the value with the `viewTitle` corresponding key, trying to send a message to it later, and as you just think of manipulating an object of type `PointOfInterest`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How should I re-assign `object`?

Comment: I solved the SIGABRT issue, but am still getting some crashing behavior in the app when I drill down into the detail view and back a couple of times.

Comment: You shouldn't.Once you initialize your object, set its properties with set values you have in `[dictionary objectForKey:viewTitle];`

Comment: Is `[dictionary objectForKey:viewTitle];` an instance of `PointOfInterest` ? I so you could just do `object = [[dictionary objectForKey:viewTitle] retain];`

Comment: The `PointOfInterest` objects populate the `dictionary` and it lives in the RootViewController.  This allows me to access a specific object from the NSMutableDictionary at any time, as well as add to it.  Here is the working code for one of the MapKit delegate methods

Comment: Check the original post now; I updated the fits section of code.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your View Controller has a view.  Mine was bombing (SIGABRT) just as described in the question because I had forgotten in IB to connect up the view outlet (which is usually created for you in your xib file) to my controller's view.